# Bundle install still not working after gem install bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I originally tried using     bundle install    but got the error 'command not found.'
I tried

```
gem install bundler
```

then tried bundle install, but still got the same error, 'bundle: command not found.'

For reference:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/opt/gems
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/willashley23/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/opt/gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/willashley23/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/opt/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec
     - /usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims
     - /Users/willashley23/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - ~/bin
     - /Users/willashley23/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/willashley23/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

**EDIT** ADDED Gemfile:

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: can you list your gemfile?

Comment: @Nirupa added above

Comment: You may want to use a tool such as rbenv(https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage gems.

Comment: @Nirupa I already have RVM and dont want to replace it.

Comment: @Nirupa Thanks but what I am I supposed to do with it?

Comment: Well I can tell you once I figure out.. Give me time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out few things according to what you have tried.

1.Install bundler to a global gemset. `rvm gemset use global && gem install bundler`

2.In case you have Homebrew installed: try `brew install ruby`

3.If the above solutions don't work the case could be that you are not sourcing rvm correctly, because you are not in a login shell, therefore run

`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

and then you can execute `bundle install`.

4.Last thing is as you are already using rvm , might be the case that rvm was not selected as default so run

```
rvm use 2.1.1 --default
```

and then run `bundle install`

5.Also you can try `rvm get head && rvm reload` before installing bundler.

Let me know if I'm missing something.